# when training data using IBM Bluemix natural language classifier api, return data too small

Tags: curl, nlp, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, nl-classifier

When I follow "Getting started with the Natural Language Classifier service" guide line, I meet problem at Stage 2: Create and train a classifier:

```
$ curl -i -u "<username>":"<password>" \
-F training_data=@<path_to_file>/weather_data_train.csv \
-F training_metadata="{\"language\":\"en\",\"name\":\"TutorialClassifier\"}" \
"https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-classifier/api/v1/classifiers"
```

It returns:

```
{
  "code" : 400,
  "error" : "Data too small",
  "description" : "The number of training entries received = 1, which is smaller
 than the required minimum of 5"
}
```

Any one could kindly help how to solve this problem. Thanks a lot~

Here is the guide line link:
http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/nl-classifier/get_start.shtml#create

Comment: are you sure you have the right path to the csv file?

Comment: Thanks Leo, It is truely caused by the incorrect path.

Comment: they could improve the error message, however :-)

Comment: Yeah, I agree, too. The error message is confused. I didn't realize I miss the '@' which cause the path problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried following the tutorial step by step and it works fine for me. I received the response "*The classifier instance is in its training phase, not yet ready to accept classify requests*" meaning that the training process started.

Please double check that you specified a correct path and that the content of the *weather_data_train.csv* file is correct: it should contain 50 lines.

I've used the following command (I executed the command within the same directory containing the .csv file):

```
$ curl -i -u "myusername":"mypwd" \
-F training_data=@./weather_data_train.csv \
-F training_metadata="{\"language\":\"en\",\"name\":\"TutorialClassifier\"}" \
"https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-classifier/api/v1/classifiers"
```

Comment: Hi Manganiello, thanks a lot. It is caused by the incorrect path. I missed character '@' after 'training_data='. It goes well after I correct it.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. But I found out the importance is the @ before the path. Without that it will not work.
training_data=@{path_to_file}